# Google Maps supported in China

Tags: google-maps

Some old documentation lists Google Maps being supported in China but hitting the end points in recent days it appears to no longer be working...

For example hitting the endpoint - http://maps.google.cn/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.934574,116.342378

Mentions an API key needs to be provided, but when it is the site crashes out with a network traffic attack style message.

Is it just that Google Maps isn't supported in China anymore or the service is down? It would be great for this to be mentioned/listed somewhere on the google support docs as I wasn't able to find anything useful describing its operation.

Comment: [This recent issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148934417) suggests that the API is no longer hosted on the CN domain since February 3. I failed to find any information on that change and they didn't answer my questions on the issue as you can see.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that is indeed how it appears and agree this could have been announced/documented somewhere better